# Wpf Bing maps control very slow on touch devices

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I am using Bing maps Wpf control.

When using on touch device (I am testing on touch screen monitor) it is very slow - Zooming, Panning, Rotating are extremely slow.

This is basically the same question as [this on msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ad1089f-866d-4b31-ab23-99687733f4b0/bing-maps-wpf-zooming-panning-rotating-on-windows-8-touch-tablet-too-sluggishly-slow-laggy?forum=bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols&prof=required), but there is no solution or workaround there.

It is obvious that this control is not optimized for touch, but I am wondering if anybody else has this problem and figured out some optimization?

Note: I have tested Windows 8 version of Bing maps control, but have to use Wpf version because it supports rotation (setting heading other than North).

Note: Number of pushpins is not important here, same problem is present with 0 pushpins.

Thanks for any help or useful suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of the WPF control was actually just released within the past month. The update consisted of bug fixes and improved touch functionality. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165

However, there are a couple of new bugs that have turned up since this release and our team has fixed them, but the new installers have not yet been released (will be soon).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ricky.

I tried the new version and it works better for touch input.

Comment: Other question:

Windows 8 version is still much faster/snappier.

Do you know if the Wpf version will be optimized further to be similar to Windows 8 version or maybe Windows 8 version could support setting Heading in next version?

Thanks

Comment: The WPF control will unlikely be as fast as the Windows 8 control. WPF is slower by nature. The Windows 8 map control was written by some of our Xbox game developers in native C++. So you will be hard pressed to beat that performance.

Comment: The bugs in the WPF control I mentioned above have been fixed. The main download page will be updated shortly, however our team has also released this as a Nuget package which is available now: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF/